# I need to export this data to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium

I got this data with selenium in python, and i want to export it to excel.

I think i could use pandas but i don`t know how i do that. Thanks for your help.

This is my code:

```py
import random
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://es.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd-historical-data?cid=1035793')

boton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
boton.click()

sleep(random.uniform(5.0, 10.0))

lista = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="data_interval"]/option[3]')
lista.click()

sleep(random.uniform(10.0, 20.0))

registro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PromoteSignUpPopUp"]/div[2]/i')
registro.click()

sleep(random.uniform(8.0, 10.0))

tablas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="curr_table"]')

rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="curr_table"]/tbody/tr'))
cols = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="curr_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td'))

print(rows)
print(cols)

for n in range(2, rows+1):
    for b in range(1, cols-4):
        fec_pre = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="curr_table"]/tbody/tr['+str(n)+']/td['+str(b)+']').text
        print(fec_pre, end='                                                                        ')
    print()
```

Comment: maybe write it as a CSV and then open in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is an array, the general syntax for exporting using Pandas is the following :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data=your_data,index=list_of_index,columns=list_of_columns)
df.to_excel(filename)
```

You can refer to the documentation for more details :
[pd.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
[to_excel function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)